# Como Compilar Assembly de 2005

Tags: assembly

Galera, Tudo bem?

Eu achei um código antigo da faculdade em Assembly, entendo que ele não funcione hoje em dia por que a codificação deve ter mudado, há alguma forma de executar ele?
Acho que programei ele perto de 2005 em um Pentium 4 HT
Segue abaixo

```
f 230 271 "Use as Teclas Q ate U, ou tambem de A ate J ou tambem de Z ate M,$"
f 272 28b "ou digite enter para sair$"
f 28c 29c "Teclado Musical$"
a100
call 305
mov ah,07 ;Ler do Teclado
int21
cmp al,71   ;Q
jnz 112
mov bl,4F
mov bh,23
jmp 200
cmp al,77   ;W
jnz 11D
mov bl,63
mov bh,1F
jmp 200
cmp al,65   ;E
jnz 128
mov bl,3F
mov bh,1C
jmp 200
cmp al,72   ;R
jnz 133
mov bl,7B
mov bh,1A
jmp 200
cmp al,74   ;T
jnz 13E
mov bl,8A
mov bh,17
jmp 200
cmp al,79   ;Y
jnz 149
mov bl,30
mov bh,15
jmp 200
cmp al,75   ;U
jnz 154
mov bl,5D
mov bh,12
jmp 200
cmp al,61   ;A
jnz 15F
mov bl,A8
mov bh,11
jmp 200
cmp al,73   ;S
jnz 16A
mov bl,B1
mov bh,0F
jmp 200
cmp al,64   ;D
jnz 175
mov bl,20
mov bh,0E
jmp 200
cmp al,66   ;F
jnz 180
mov bl,3E
mov bh,0D
jmp 200
cmp al,67   ;G
jnz 18A
mov bl,C5
mov bh,0B
jmp 200
cmp al,68   ;H
jnz 194
mov bl,98
mov bh,0A
jmp 200
cmp al,6A   ;J
jnz 19E
mov bl,6A
mov bh,09
jmp 200
cmp al,7A   ;Z
jnz 1a8
mov bl,D4
mov bh,08
jmp 200
cmp al,78   ;X
jnz 1b2
mov bl,D9
mov bh,07
jmp 200
cmp al,63   ;C
jnz 1bc
mov bl,10
mov bh,07
jmp 200
cmp al,76   ;V
jnz 1c6
mov bl,9F
mov bh,06
jmp 200
cmp al,62   ;B
jnz 1d0
mov bl,E3
mov bh,05
jmp 200
cmp al,6E   ;N
jnz 1da
mov bl,4C
mov bh,05
jmp 200
cmp al,6D   ;M
jnz 1E4
mov bl,B5
mov bh,04
jmp 200
cmp al,0d
jz 1eb
jmp 103
int 20

a200
mov al,e6   ;seta
out 43,al
mov al,bl   ;Poem o bl(menos significativo) no al
out 42,al
mov al,bh   ;Poem o bh(mais significativo) no al
out 42,al
in al,61    ;Seta a dispositivo de som.
or al,03    ;Liga apenas os 2 bits necessários.
out 61,al
int 1a
mov bx,dx
add bx,09
cmp bx,dx
int 1a
jnc 219
in al,61    ;Para o som
and al,Fc
out 61,al
jmp 103

a305
mov ah,02   ;pos cursor
mov dh,01
mov dl,0f
int 10
mov dx,28C  ;Mensagem do enter
mov ah,09
int 21
mov ah,02   ;pos cursor
mov dh,0f
mov dl,0f
int 10
mov dx,230  ;Mensagem do enter
mov ah,09
int 21
mov ah,02   ;pos cursor
mov dh,10
mov dl,0f
int 10
mov dx,272  ;Mensagem do enter
mov ah,09
int 21
mov ah,02   ;pos cursor
mov dh,15
mov dl,0f
int 10
mov dx,29d  ;Mensagem do enter
mov ah,09
int 21
ret


2ª oitava:
234F = Dó   ;letra Q
1F63 = Ré   ;letra w
1C3F = Mi   ;letra E
1A7B = Fá   ;letra R
178A = Sol  ;letra T
1530 = Lá   ;letra Y
12D5 = Si   ;letra U

3ª oitava:
11A8 = Dó   ;letra A
0FB1 = Ré   ;letra S
0E20 = Mi   ;letra D
0D3E = Fá   ;letra F
0BC5 = Sol  ;letra G
0A98 = Lá   ;letra H
096A = Si   ;letra J

4ª oitava:
08D4 = Dó   ;letra Z
07D9 = Ré   ;letra X
0710 = Mi   ;letra C
069F = Fá   ;letra V
05E3 = Sol  ;letra B
054C = Lá   ;letra N
04B5 = Si   ;letra M
```

Comment: E porque não funcionaria?

Comment: Eu não uso isso a muitos anos, pode me explicar como fazer?

Comment: É importante [edit] o post e colocar o que tentou e qual o problema encontrado. Se o que busca é um tutorial de como montar o código, não é exatamente o escopo do site.

Comment: Parece que esse código foi escrito para MS-DOS ou velhos versões de Windows, porque usa o 'int 21h'. DOSBOX emula MS-DOS muito bem. Talvez pode usá-lo para compilar com uma programa como 'yasm' e executar.